# OpenGL: glGetError() not ressetting its flag?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am trying to debug my code using glGetError() but I noticed it was throwing error 1282 every time I called it. Eventually I called glGetError() 2 lines in a row and BOTH gave error 1282.

Shouldnt it have reset the error flag after the first call, causing the second to return 0? Or does this function work differently than I thought?

Answer (score 4):

Pump [it](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) 'till it's dry:

> To allow for distributed implementations, there may be several error flags. If any single error flag has recorded an error, the value of that flag is returned and that flag is reset to GL_NO_ERROR when glGetError is called. If more than one flag has recorded an error, glGetError returns and clears an arbitrary error flag value. Thus, **glGetError should always be called in a loop, until it returns GL_NO_ERROR**, if all error flags are to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

I found why the flag may be not resetting: it is only happening when the program exits, the loop become really infinite. So the reason should be in the OpenGL itself, mostly because de-initialization of different part of the library is done in the order we don't know. Solution: pump it until it is dry, or until the counter reaches maximum:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define GLAD_GET_ERROR_MAX 25
void gladGetError(_In_z_ const char* zFuncName)
{
    GLenum eNumber;
    for (int i = 0; i < GLAD_GET_ERROR_MAX; i++)
    {
        if ((eNumber = glGetError()) == GL_NO_ERROR) break;
        const char* zDescription = NULL;
        switch (eNumber)
        {
            case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
                zDescription = "INVALID ENUM";
                break;
            case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
                zDescription = "INVALID VALUE";
                break;
            case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
                zDescription = "INVALID OPERATION";
                break;
            case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                zDescription = "OUT OF MEMORY";
#ifdef GL_VERSION_3_0
                break;
            case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:
                zDescription = "INVALID FRAMEBUFFER OPERATION";
#endif // #ifdef GL_VERSION_3_0
            }
            std::cout << "GLAD <" << zFuncName << "> ERROR <" << eNumber << ">: " << zDescription << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

// Macro to trace your code in Debug version
#define GLAD_GET_ERROR(z) gladGetError(z);
#else
#define GLAD_GET_ERROR(z)
#endif // #ifdef _DEBUG

// USAGE!
GLAD_GET_ERROR("Your function name where the error might occur")
```